# conditional statement for getting TextView

Tags: android, robotium, black-box-testing

I have to get a `EditText` object which is nothing but a search bar in app with text visible as `Current Location`, however if I've already made a search query with `myText`, there is no `Current Location` text visible and search bar shows `myText`.

I am writing the test cases using [Robotium](https://code.google.com/p/robotium/) solo object.

How can i write a conditional statement to get the `EditText` despite of what text it shows. Something like

```
if !found solo.getText("Current Location")
      search solo.getText("myText");
```

This is what I am doing currently

```
EditText text = (EditText) solo.getText("Current Location");
if(text == null){
        text = (EditText) solo.getText("myText");
//my rest of the code goes here....
```

But this throws exception if `Current Location` is not present in the search bar.

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: TextView with text: 'Current Location' is not found!
```

Please suggest the correct way.

Comment: What is the `solo` object?

Comment: its Robotium. The android automation tool.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code:

```
if(!solo.searchText("Current Location"))
    assertTrue(solo.searchText("my Text"))
else
    assertTrue(solo.searchText("Current Location"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText view = (EditText) solo.getView(view1);

if(view == null){
    view = (EditText) solo.getView(view2)
}
view.getText().toString();
```